# How to find common intervals between hours?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays with intervals:

```
[
  [
    [8:00,  11:30], // [begin,end]
    [12:00, 16:00], // [begin,end]
    [18:00, 21:00]  // [begin,end]
  ],
  [
    [8:00,  15:30], // [begin,end]
    [16:00, 17:45], // [begin,end]
    [19:00, 21:30]  // [begin,end]
  ]
]
```

I need to find common intervals for these hours, so it should be:

```
[
  [8:00,  11:30],
  [12:00, 15:30],
  [19:00, 21:00]
]
```

I changed hours to minutes and then compared intervals from first array with intervals in second array but output isn't like it is shown upper.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
 let hours = [[[8:00,11:30],[12:00,16:00],[18:00,21:00]]
    [[8:00,15:30],[16:00,17:45],[19:00,21:30]]]  

    let commonHors=[];
    for (let i=0; i<(hours||[]).length; i++){
      for(let j=0; j<(hours||[])[i].length; j++){

        let fromFirst = moment.duration(hours[0][j][0]).minutes() + 
        moment.duration(hours[0][j][0]).hours()*60;

        let fromSec = moment.duration(hours[1][j][0]).minutes() + 
        moment.duration(hours[1][j][0]).hours()*60;

        let toFirst = moment.duration(hours[0][j][1]).minutes() + 
        moment.duration(hours[0][j][1]).hours()*60;

        let toSec = moment.duration(hours[1][j][1]).minutes() + 
        moment.duration(hours[0][j][1]).hours()*60;

        if(fromFirst >=  fromSec && toFirst <= toSec){
          commonHors.push(hours[0][j][0],hours[0][j][1]);
        }
        else if(fromFirst <=  fromSec && toFirst <= toSec){
          commonHors.push(hours[1][j][0],hours[0][j][1]);
        }
        else if(fromFirst >=  fromSec && toFirst >= toSec){
          commonHors.push(hours[0][j][0],hours[1][j][1]);
        }        
        else if(fromFirst <=  fromSec && toFirst >= toSec){
          commonHors.push(hours[1][j][0],hours[1][j][1]);
        }     
      }
    }
```

Comment: you'll have to define what you mean by "common intervals" more clearly. It's not immediately clear (to me, anyway) why the desired results you've shown are the correct ones. What are the rules you used to derive them? And also, what is going wrong in the code currently? Are you getting errors, or incorrect output? Please be clear so we don't have to start again and re-do all the same debugging you've (hopefully) already carried out before you got stuck.

Comment: It looked like your common interval was three and a half hours based off of the first two inner-arrays `[8:00,  11:30],[12:00, 15:30]` but the last one is a two hour interval `[19:00, 21:00]`?  If finding intervals that equaled the same was the objective, that last time interval confused me, if that was indeed the solution as you said it was.

Comment: I edited a little bit my answer. These hours in arrays are begin hour and end hour. I need to find new intervals which hours will belong to hours in the first array and the second array at the same time. This interval: [19:00, 21:00] is ok, because 19:00 is between [18:00, 21:00], but 21:30 not, so 21:00 is the last hour (21:00 is in [18:00, 21:00])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by far not the most beautiful solution, but it works under the condition that the input data is valid and already sorted. I hope I understood your problem and my solution is helpful. edit: I used strings instead of other time-formats - just realized but it should not be difficult to change that since I sorted by numeric value;

```
let intervals = [
    [
        ['8:00',  '11:30'],
        ['12:00',  '16:00'],
        ['18:00',  '21:00']
    ],
    [
        ['8:00',  '15:30'],
        ['16:00', '17:45'],
        ['19:00', '21:30']
    ]
];

let out = [];


while(intervals[0].length > 0) {

    let laterNum = later(0, 0);
    let startTime = intervals[laterNum][0][0];
    let earlyNum = earlier(0, 1);
    let endTime = intervals[earlyNum][0][1];

    if (Number(endTime.replace(':', '')) > Number(startTime.replace(':', '')))
        out.push([startTime, endTime]);

    intervals[earlyNum].splice(0, 1);

}

function earlier(line, time) {
    let a = intervals[0][line][time];
    let b = intervals[1][line][time];

    return Number(a.replace(':', '')) < Number(b.replace(':', '')) ? 0 : 1;
}

function later(line, time) {
    return earlier(line, time) === 1 ? 0 : 1;
}


console.log(out);
```